# Django -- Value hard-set after upload

Tags: python, django

So I have this model class

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=_upload_path)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    user_id = user.primary_key
    options = 0

    _upload_path = #...
```

which is used by two upload functions

```
def list(request):
    newdoc = None
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.user = request.user
            newdoc.options = 0
            newdoc.save()
            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('notendur.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # An empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(# stuff)
```

and

```
def reikna(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_doc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            new_doc.user = request.user
            # Marks the file as /options/ file
            new_doc.options = 1
            new_doc.save()

    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # An empty, unbound form

    render_to_response( #stuff )
```

So the `options` attribute acts as an identifier between the two upload functions, so I know which document was uploaded by which function. My problem is that the `options` attribute seems to be set to `0`, no matter what I do.

Comment: This perhaps would not answer your question, but don't call function list, because it is reserved name.

Comment: You're right, it's best I change that.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment on your question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436363/new-class-attribute-not-added-to-models-db-table-in-django), you should not be setting `options = 0` on your model and instead should say `models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)`. Also, specifying `user_id` on your model is unnecessary since you already specified the `User` ForeignKey