# New class attribute not added to model's DB table in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model class

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=_upload_path)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    user_id = user.primary_key
    options = 0

    def get_upload_path(self,filename):
        return "uploads/"+str(self.user.id) + '/' + str(date.today()) + '/' + filename
```

The class worked fine until I added the `options` attribute. When I type `./manage.py sql myapp` I don't see the options row, and all `Document` objects have their `options` attribute hard-set to 0. I have South and Django 1.6. What I did was

```
./manage.py migrate myapp
```

which said "there's nothing to migrate."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you missed the schemamigration step.. Also, `options=0` is not valid. `option = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)` - Note, you dont need the `user_id` in the model. You get that for free when you do `user = ForeignKey...`

Comment: Yes! That was what I was missing. I've been trying to figure this out all day. Thanks a lot again.